# How to send Html formatted mail instead of default email format in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, html-email

How can we send a html formatted mail in Drupal 8 instead of default format that given by Drupal core.
Such as default email format for user account creation, how can we send this in Html format?

[Drupal 8 account creation email format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYRLZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the [HTML Mail](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/html-mail) module but the drupal 8 version is still in alpha :/ .

Another simple alternative is to implement `hook_mail_alter` in order to :

- Set the proper content-type in the message headers.
- Use the proper formatter to preserve HTML tags (which, by default, would be escaped).
- Put HTML tags in email messages without relying on additional module.

The only thing to do now is to write some HTML in the messages, and this should do the job :

```
/**
 * Implements hook_mail_alter().
 */
function modulename_mail_alter(&$message) {
  switch ($message['key']) {
    case 'register_admin_created':
    #case '<other HTML message id>': 
    #...
      $message['headers']['Content-Type'] = 'text/html; charset=UTF-8;';
      foreach ($message['body'] as $key => &$body) {
        $body = new Drupal\Component\Render\FormattableMarkup($body, []);
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response.I tried Html Mail module, but it didn't work. May be because as you said it is still in development phase. Is there any other module like this in D8? Why i am asking because i know hook_mail_alter is an option but it is not helpful when an end user want to change the format of the mail.

Comment: It could be though, just by checking what is the expected email format for the end user, and let the hook work according to. Just add an `if` statement before the `switch`.